# Lazy loading from CDN

Tags: angular

Is it possible to load lazy modules from external server? I'd like to upload my resources onto CDN, but it seems, the lazy modules are loading from my node.js server which is not good for me.

My server serves only the index.html of angular app, but the resources will be loaded from cdn. It starts and works fine till a lazy module should be loaded which is relative to my server not to CDN.

Comment: This is a WebPack issue, and you would have to use a custom WebPack configuration. There isn't any options in Angular to change the URL for lazy loading. There is only limit support to change the name of the chunk files.

Comment: I don't use webpack directly. The resources are built with the CLI and I'd like to serve them as static resource from CDN.

Answer (score 0):

The following will set where it looks for the lazy loaded modules.  (You can add it to angular.json as well)

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url https://yourcdn.com/path/
```

This also works

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url /path/to/javascript/
```

It is listed here

```
ng build --help
```

I am using AngularCLI 7.0.5  I have not checked what version they added this flag.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the actual code-split assets. main.js, runtime.js, and all the css get referenced from the CDN but all the code-split files (1.js etc) still get referenced locally.

Answer (score 0):

To set lazyloaded module path use `--deploy-url`

```
ng build --deploy-url=/dist/some_folder
ng build --deploy-url=//localhost:5021/dist/cdn/
```

To change assets path use `--base-url=/asset/path`

so to load assets locally and lazy loaded modules from CDN

```
ng build --base-url=/asset/path --deploy-url=//localhost:5021/dist/cdn/
```