# How do I set the deploy-url at runtime to change the path of lazy loaded modules?

Tags: angular

**Background**

I have an existing Angular 7 application which is built once (into a docker image) but then hosted on multiple servers.  Each server has a different root url and (given an environment variable) settings for testing or production.

Up until now the routing has been happy with setting `<base href="<rooturl>">`.

Even though it is a singe code base, it runs with different base urls on the different servers.

**Present Problem**

Now I am expanding the app and adding a child router.  I want to do it the 'blessed' way which includes lazy loading the modules.

The problem is that the code is trying to load 'http://www.example.com/3.js'.

To be clear, I do NOT want it to load the modules based on the base url used by the router.  I need the lazy loaded modules to come from our CDNs.

I have read that adding --deploy-url can fix the problem, but that would require building a separate docker image for every deploy location - which doesn't make sense.

**Question**

How do I set the url used to lazy load modules (deploy url?) in the html OR in the angular bootstrap code?

Thanks.

**Edit**

As far as I can tell, APP_BASE_HREF is the replacement for base href tag I mentioned above.

I am trying to find something similar for the deploy url.

Comment: what about providers:[... {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/rooturl'},] ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108316/how-can-i-loadchildren-in-my-routes-when-my-module-is-on-some-cdn

Comment: another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773869/lazy-loading-from-cdn